# R Pivot multiple columns from wide to long

Tags: r, pivot-table

I am unsure how to use pivot longer when I need to pivot multiple columns(but not all columns) from wide to long.

Starting Data:

```
    dat <- tibble(aColumn = c("stuff", "stuff", "stuff"),
               anotherColumn = c("more stuff", "more stuff", "more stuff"),
               `Day a Time` = c("12:00", "13:00", "14:00"),
               `Day a Value` = c("R", "I", "O"),
               `Day b Time` = c("12:45", "14:00", "15:35"),
               `Day b Value` = c("R", "P", "O"))
```

FinalData:

```
desiredDat <- tibble(aColumn = rep("stuff", 6),
       anotherColumn = rep("more stuff", 6),
       DayID = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
       DayTime = c("12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "12:45", "14:00", "15:35"),
       DayValue = c("R","I","O","R","P","O"))
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `pivot_longer` after rearranging the column names substring.  We `rename` the columns that starts with 'Day' by rearraning the the words i.e. the substring 'a', 'b' in the column name is shifted to the end with the delimiter `_` by capturing those words (`(\\w+)`)  and then in the replacement for `str_replace`, changing the backreference order (`\\1`, `\\2` etc)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
     rename_at(vars(starts_with('Day')), 
       ~ str_replace(., '(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+)', "\\1\\3_\\2")) %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Day'), 
           names_to = c( ".value", "DayID"), names_sep="_")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  aColumn anotherColumn DayID DayTime DayValue
#  <chr>   <chr>         <chr> <chr>   <chr>   
#1 stuff   more stuff    a     12:00   R       
#2 stuff   more stuff    b     12:45   R       
#3 stuff   more stuff    a     13:00   I       
#4 stuff   more stuff    b     14:00   P       
#5 stuff   more stuff    a     14:00   O       
#6 stuff   more stuff    b     15:35   O
```

Comment: This works. Can you elaborate a tiny bit on the regex? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you could do:

```
dat1 <- setNames(dat, sub(" (\\w+) (\\w+)$",'\\2 \\1', names(dat)))

tms <- unique(sub('\\w+ (\\w) \\w+', '\\1', names(df)[-(1:2)]))

reshape(dat1, -(1:2), dir='long', times = tms, sep=' ')

    aColumn anotherColumn time DayTime DayValue id
1.a   stuff    more stuff    a   12:00        R  1
2.a   stuff    more stuff    a   13:00        I  2
3.a   stuff    more stuff    a   14:00        O  3
1.b   stuff    more stuff    b   12:45        R  1
2.b   stuff    more stuff    b   14:00        P  2
3.b   stuff    more stuff    b   15:35        O  3
```

Then you could change the column names to what you want