# R, Pivot longer, multiple observations per row

Tags: r, tidyverse

I think I have a question that is nearly identical to this one: [R Pivot multiple columns from wide to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794642/r-pivot-multiple-columns-from-wide-to-long) but I am hopelessly lost on the regex when trying to follow along.

I am also trying to pivot data to be longer, and I also have multiple columns I'd like to save.  My data currently:

```
FollowUpScans<-structure(list(study_id = c(40, 44, 49, 61, 66, 67, 68, 84, 86, 
94, 95, 101, 123, 126, 131, 153, 154, 155, 156, 161, 166, 169, 
175, 185, 199, 203, 207, 211, 217, 221, 227, 256, 257, 259, 266, 
275, 284, 301, 306, 307, 309, 313, 320, 353, 382, 392, 398, 401, 
402, 412, 415, 428, 431, 433, 434, 436), Score1 = c(3, 0, 4, 
4, NA, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 4, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7, 5, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 
3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2), TimeBetweenScans = structure(c(316, 
113, 335, 104, 7, 42, 30, 643, 404, 40, 171, 51, 449, 56, 104, 
79, 116, 65, 39, 1193, 142, 106, 221, 36, 125, 137, 927, 63, 
156, 32, 411, 201, 160, 166, 459, 212, 50, 312, 1627, 354, 33, 
62, 842, 174, 216, 17, 214, 24, 149, 72, 9, 13, 42, 771, 113, 
122), class = "difftime", units = "days"), Score2 = c(NA, 0, 
7, NA, NA, NA, 0, 7, NA, 5, 8, 0, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 9, NA, 
NA, 0, 4, NA, NA, 0, 9, 2, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
1, 8, NA, NA, 3, NA, 0, 8, NA, 5, NA, 7, NA, 0, 3, NA, 7, NA, 
4), TimeBetweenScans2 = structure(c(NA, 139, 660, NA, NA, NA, 
84, 1794, NA, 221, 320, 227, NA, NA, NA, 989, NA, NA, 411, NA, 
NA, 216, 474, NA, NA, 372, 1006, 429, 447, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 313, 530, 1706, NA, NA, 130, NA, 300, 264, NA, 268, NA, 
382, NA, 38, 138, NA, 1200, 166, 475), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    Score3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 4, NA, NA, 0, NA, 5, 
    0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 0, 4), TimeBetweenScans3 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 467, NA, NA, 394, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    1097, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 266, 796, NA, NA, 941, NA, 533, 
    470, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 783, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 388, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1512, 180, 640
    ), class = "difftime", units = "days"), Score4 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 5, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), TimeBetweenScans4 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 826, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 497, NA, NA, NA, 1102, NA, 567, 1204, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1574, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    Score5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    TimeBetweenScans5 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 575, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1225, NA, NA, 1266, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-56L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And instead of columns that looks like:  study_id, Score1, TimeBetweenScans,Score2,TimeBetweenScans2, Score3, TimeBetweenScans3,etc.etc..

I'd love it to ultimately look like: study_id,Score,Time,Occurence

The "Occurence" column would just have a 1,2,3,4 etc.. to demonstrate which column it came from.  The study_id column would be nice to keep because it demonstrates which "person" it came from.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Here's a `data.table` approach: `library(data.table); setnames(FollowUpScans, "TimeBetweenScans", "TimeBetweenScans1"); melt(as.data.table(FollowUpScans), measure.vars=patterns("^Score", "^TimeBetweenScans"))` I don't know if your first "TimeBetweenScans" column is really missing the numeric suffix as it is in the data you shared here.

Comment: Thank you.  As for the "TimeBetweenScans" missing a numeric suffix.... yea it shouldn't have been theoretically but it is.  Your approach worked great, I'll leave the question up as I guess I'd love a tidyverse approach but thank you.

Comment: Then I would think that something like `FollowUpScans %>% pivot_longer(-1, names_to = c(".value", "Time"), names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)")` should work (maybe after renaming the column, like I did with "data.table" as well). Not tested...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to rename it to make sure the times match up correctly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
FollowUpScans %>%
  rename(TimeBetweenScans1 = TimeBetweenScans) %>%
  pivot_longer(-study_id, 
    names_to = c(".value", "Time"), 
    names_pattern = "([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+)")
```

The steps are:

- Rename the column that is likely to cause problems
- `pivot_longer` specifying that the columns are named in a *any number of characters* followed by *any number of digits* pattern. You can use different regex patterns than the one I've shared here. For example, you could probably use `"(.*)(\\d+)"` for this particular dataset.

If you *don't* rename first, I would suspect that you would end up with too many rows. You should end up with `nrow(FollowUpScans) * 5` rows.